# How do I prevent Arabic letters from connecting to each other in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Arabic letters not being connected was the default in Sublime Text, but I cannot figure out how to turn it off in [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com). I tried disabling ligatures, etc. but nothing has fixed it for me.

This is what it looks like in Sublime Text; this is good:

[image: Arabic text in Sublime Text.]

And this is what it looks like in VS Code; the connecting of characters is what I want to turn off so it looks more like what it is like in Sublime Text:

[image: Arabic text in VS Code.]

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a kerning setting. Have you seen [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106061)?

Comment: @JakeGould , i tried that, but it really doesn't solve the issue. It adds space between the letters, but they still are converted to the connected forms. additionally, this setting also changes the spacing for english letters, which i do not want to change

Comment: Thanks for the pics! I also notice that Sublime Text is showing the characters as left to right (Western text) while VS Code is showing characters as right to left (Arabic norm I assume). Wonder if that is a clue?

Comment: yes, you're right. Sublime doesn't do Arabic right to left, but for my purposes (string manipulations), it is actually easier that way. I tried to find a way to disable RTL for Arabic in VS code, but was unsuccessful